# Different output in run and debug while reading file

Tags: java, fileinputstream

I am trying to read a file by reading chunks at a time using FileInputStream in Java. 
The code is following:

```
        File file = new File(filepath);
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] chunk = new byte[bytelength];
        int chunkLen = chunk.length;
        long lineCnt = 0;

        while ((chunkLen = is.read(chunk)) != -1) {

            String decoded = getchunkString(chunk);
            System.out.println(decoded);

            System.out.println("---------------------------------");

        }
```

I am taking bytelength =128 and trying to test with a smaller file as follows:

```
graph G{
biz -- mai
biz -- ded
biz -- ronpepsi
blaine -- dan
dan -- graysky
dan -- iancr
dan -- maxwell
dan -- foursquare
blaine -- neb
}
```

when I run the code it reads the chunk like this:

```
graph G{
biz -- mai
biz -- ded
biz -- ronpepsi
blaine -- dan
dan -- graysky
dan -- iancr
dan -- maxwell
dan -- foursquare
blaine
---------------------------------
 -- neb
}
iz -- mai
biz -- ded
biz -- ronpepsi
blaine -- dan
dan -- graysky
dan -- iancr
dan -- maxwell
dan -- foursquare
blaine
---------------------------------
```

I don't understand how the 2nd chunk comes? I hope it should be only

```
-- neb
    }
```

when i debugg  `is.read(chunk)` becomes 10 and then -1 and it prints only the first chunk.

Comment: If you are reading a text file, you can use FileReader (wrapped in BufferedReader)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is chance that the buffer may contain garbage data, so you need to use bytes only up to bytes read i.e. chunkLen in your case.

```
while ((chunkLen = is.read(chunk)) != -1) {
   for (int i = 0; i < chunkLen; i++){
    //read the bytes here
   }
}
```

or you can use String constructor as below

```
while ((chunkLen = is.read(chunk)) != -1) {
   String decoded = new String(chunk, 0, chunkLen);
   System.out.println(decoded);
   System.out.println("---------------------------------");
}
```

You need to modify your code accordingly.

Comment: yes the issue was the garbage data so clearing will also work .. how did you clear it ? by creating new byte[] ?